# Testing javascript functions - that are not visible to controller (angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am using the controller as syntax from angular and i want to test my code using jasmine and sinon.

Let's say i want the following controller code :

```
angular
    .module('Test')
    .controller('TestController', TestController);

TestController.$inject = [];

function TestController() {
         var viewModel = this;

         viewModel.myFunction = myFunction;

         function myFunction(){
            //do something
            //now call a helper function
            helperFunction()
         }

         function helperFunction(){
             // ....
         }
}
```

My question is how i can test the helperFunction() or even put a spy on it ? My helper is not visible in my test.

Here is my test :

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

     var myController;

     describe('Test', function () {

         beforeEach(module('Test'));

         beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $injector) {         
               myController = $controller('TestController');
         }));

         it('Tests helperFunction', function (){

              var sinonSpy = sinon.spy(myController, 'helperFunction');

              //perform the action
              myController.myFunction();

             //expect the function was called - once
             expect(sinonSpy .callCount).toEqual(1);
          }
    })
 })
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have access to those functions. When you define a named JS function it's the same as saying:

```
var helperFunction = function(){};
```

In which case it would be pretty clear to see that the var is only in the scope within the block and there is no external reference to it from the wrapping controller.

To make a function testable, you need to add it to the $scope of the controller.

```
viewModel.helperFunction = helperFunction;
```

But be aware that is not a good idea to be exposing everything just to make it testable. You really need to consider if testing it will actually add some value to your project

Answer (score 0):

try to do so :

```
 var vm = controller("helperFunction", { $scope: scope });
```

and then:

```
vm.myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code into your controller:

```
  angular.extend($scope, {
      helperFunction:helperFunction
    });
```